# How to display an icon from a json string in a Label

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have: [api](https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/hourly?city=Plovdiv,BG&key=690e088fd504485fb47695c66bcef94e&hours=48) and want to display Icon in array weather -> Icon.

For now I display only the string in this API on the display screen on iOS but I can't see the icon image.

My `MainPage.xaml` look like this:

```
             <Frame CornerRadius="10"  
                   OutlineColor="Red"
                   Margin="10,0,10,0"
                   BackgroundColor="White"
                   Opacity="0.5">

                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">          
                    <Label x:Name="infoLabel"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                   FontSize="15" />
                     <Label x:Name="infoLabel1"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                   FontSize="15" />
                </StackLayout> 
            </Frame>
```

My `MainPage.xaml.cs` look like this:

```
string Info = DateDays.DayOfWeek + DateDays.ToString(" MM/dd - HH:mm") + " " + weatherData.weatherForecast[0].Weather.Icon + " " + weatherData.weatherForecast[0].Temperature + "°C";
            infoLabel.Text = Info;

            string Info1 = DateDays1.DayOfWeek + DateDays1.ToString(" MM/dd - HH:mm") + " " + weatherData.weatherForecast[1].Weather.Icon + " " + weatherData.weatherForecast[1].Temperature + "°C";
            infoLabel1.Text = Info1;
```

And the result is: [image]

What is the correct way to show the icon?

Comment: it would probably be a good idea to start by reading the API docs that describe how the weather icon works

Comment: What you mean  ?

Comment: the docs show you how to translate "r01n" into an image url

Comment: Can you give me some url with documentation, please ?

Comment: https://www.weatherbit.io/api/codes

Comment: What is the principle of this? Do I have to manually download all the icons to load them with a code check?

Comment: There is no documentation on how to display in this link. I have all the things in my object. My question is how to display them ?

Comment: "r01n" => https://www.weatherbit.io/static/img/icons/r01n.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to translate the code "r01n" into a url.  See https://www.weatherbit.io/api/codes

```
<Image Source="https://www.weatherbit.io/static/img/icons/r01n.png" />
```

you can build the url like this

```
var url = $"https://www.weatherbit.io/static/img/icons/{weatherData.weatherForecast[0].Weather.Icon}.png";
```

Comment: Can you give me some example how to replace the name before .png with if else statemant ?

Comment: see expanded example

Comment: Work Perfect ! Thanks !